# Access master page control in content page through javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I am having a problem in accessing Master Page Label in Content page through javascript

Here's the code:

MasterPage Code:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-2  hidden-sm  hidden-xs">
            <!-- Cart in header -->
        <div class="header-cart">                    
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblsubtotal" CssClass="lblcart"></asp:Label></span>
                <i class="icon1-shopping-cart" style="color: #85a504; font-size: 30px;"></i>
                <!-- Open cart panel -->
            <div class="header-cart__open-cart" style="height: 350px; overflow: auto">
                 <div id="CartContent" style="height: auto; width: auto">Loading please wait...</div>
                 <hr id="hrempty" runat="server" class="header-cart__divider" />
               <div class="header-cart__product__box">
                 <span class="header-cart__product__subtotal">CART SUBTOTAL:</span>
                 <span class="header-cart__product__subtotal-price"><i class="icon1-inr" style="font-size: 20px;"></i>
                 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblsubtot"></asp:Label></span>
               </div>                      
           </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Content Page Code (Products.aspx)

```
   $.ajax({
                            url: '/ViewProducts.aspx/AjaxShowCart',
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            //      data: '{ "startindex":"' + startIndex + '", "pagesize":"' + pageSize + '"}',
                            success: function (result) {
                                $('#img_loading').hide();
                                var count11 = 0;
                                $.each(result.d, function () {
                                    count11 = count11 + 1;
                                });

                                if (count11 > 0) {
  // Here I've been trying to access label named lblsubtot, lblsubtotal and div named CartContent with different methods.. But I am not able to acces them.

                                    var lbl = Master.FindControl("ContentPageHolder1").FindControl(lblsubtot);
                                    var subtot = document.getElementsByClassName["lblcart"];
                                    var no = document.getElementById('<%=Page.Master.FindControl("lblsubtot").ClientID %>').value;      
                                    parent.document.getElementById('CartContent').textContent = "";
                                    parent.document.getElementById('CartTemplate').tmpl(result.d).appendTo(parent.document.getElementById('CartContent'));
                                }
                                else {
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Tell me if there's any way to access those labels (lblsubtot, lblsubtotal and CartContent) of master page in ContentPage.
Thanx In advance

Comment: This should work `var subtot = document.getElementsByClassName("lblcart");`  what errors do you get client side?

Comment: Hey it works with this:
var subtot = $('.lblcart').val